# Flower doesn't show task events

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, flower

[Here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.send_event) I find how to send event to Flower. Next, I try to use it in my code like in [github issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3656). My version:

```
@celery.task()
def add():
    try:
        ...
    except Exception as exc:
        add.send_event('task-failed', exception=str(exc))
```

In case of error, Flower receives information about failed task:

[Flower's dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFwIu.png)

But when I try to click and find extra inforamtion about it, I see:

[Information about failed tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwrm3.png)

How should I use `send_event` ?

Comment: Celery after it also sends event about task's result, state and this event rewrites all previous information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

`send_event` uses `task.request.id` to publish event into Flower. If replace this id to another, in Flower will be two records about one task. But need to use different ids for these records. Example of function:

```
def send_to_flower(task, event, **kwargs):
    task.request.id = str(uuid4())
    task.send_event(event, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your searching for the wrong state. You should be searching for `state:FAILED` not `state:FAILURE`.